# Add items with same date to sub list of item main list

Tags: c#, list, date, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have list of items in main list and main list has sub list and now I need all items in main list where have same date add how items of sub list. Does anyone know any recommendation? Here is sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/Sn%C3%ADmka.PNG

```
public class calendarData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public DateTime HOURstartDT { get; set; }
}

 public static List<List<calendarData>> getCalList()
    {

        List<calendarData> lessons = new List<calendarData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < test.getResp().GetStudies(0).LessonsList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).HoursCount; j++)
            {
            lessons.Add(new calendarData
            {
                name = test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).Name,
                shortName = test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).Shortname,
                HOURstartDT = new DateTime(test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).GetHours(j).StartTime.Year, test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).GetHours(j).StartTime.Month, test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).GetHours(j).StartTime.Day, test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).GetHours(j).StartTime.Hour, test.getResp().GetStudies(0).GetLessons(i).GetHours(j).StartTime.Minute, 0),

            });

            }  
        }

        List<List<calendarData>> listOfList=new List<List<calendarData>>();

        foreach (calendarData subList in lessons)
        {
            listOfList.Add(new List<calendarData> {subList});
        }
        return listOfList;
    }
```

Now I get result: List of 10 item and every items have list with one item. How I can compare HOURstartDT and all items of first list which have same date I need add to sublist of main list.

Example: Main list: item 1: name= "Jon", Date=14.6.2013  item 2:name="Steve", Date=15.6.2013, item 3:name="Michael", Date=14.6.2013

I need items with same date(14.6.2013) add to sub list like items and remove these items from main list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you solution with the static data. You can use that.

```
public List<List<calendarData>> getCalList()
{
    List<List<calendarData>> StaticData = new List<List<calendarData>> 
    {
        new List<calendarData> 
        {
            new calendarData
            {
                name = "Jon Jon",
                shortName = "Jon",
                HOURstartDT = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
            }
        },

        new List<calendarData> 
        {
            new calendarData
            {
                name = "Steve Steve",
                shortName = "Steve",
                HOURstartDT = DateTime.Now.Date
            }
        },

        new List<calendarData> 
        {
            new calendarData
            {
                name = "Michael Michael",
                shortName = "Michael",
                HOURstartDT = DateTime.Now.Date
            }
        }
    };

    //return StaticData.GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault().HOURstartDT).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
    return StaticData.SelectMany(x => x).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.HOURstartDT).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, using linq

```
var mySubList = lessons.Where(l => l.HOURstartDT == AddYourDataHere);
mySubList.ForEach(item => 
           {
               lessons.remove(item);
           });
```

Not sure I understand the full question, but this will be a start

Comment: ForEach doesnt exist in windows store .(